# Replace All Specific Characters in String using Python

Tags: python, loops, recursion

I have a problem with a function I am trying to implement that needs to replace some letters (in a given string), for some other characters, defined on a dictionary.

I have this dictionary:

```
chars = {
        'A': ['4', '@'],
        'E': ['3', '€', '&', '£'],
        'T': ['7'],
        'S': ['$', '§', '5'],
        'I': ['1', '!'],
        'O': ['0'],
        'B': ['8'],
        'C': ['<'],
        'L': ['1']
    }
```

I want to pass a string that when a character matches any key from the dictionary (case insensitive match), it tries to save all the possible combinations for that letter, using the values on the dictionary.

Here's what I currently have:

```
def type4 (words, v):
    chars = {
        'A': ['4', '@'],
        'E': ['3', '€', '&', '£'],
        'T': ['7'],
        'S': ['$', '§', '5'],
        'I': ['1', '!'],
        'O': ['0'],
        'B': ['8'],
        'C': ['<'],
        'L': ['1']
    }

    tmp = []
    string = []
    for w in words:                                 # each character in a word
        for key in chars.keys():                    # [A, E, T, S, I, O, B, C, L]
            for c in chars[key]:                    # [4, @, 3, €, &, £, ...]
                string = list(w)                    
                k = 0                               
                ya = ""
                for char in string:
                    if (char == key or char == key.lower()):
                        string[k] = c
                    else:
                        string[k] = char
                    k += 1
                if (not string == list(w)):
                    for i in string:
                        ya += i
                    print(ya, end="\n\n")

                tmp.append(ya)

    return tmp
```

In the current code, I have only replaced a character on the string. I need to change it so that it matches the output below,

The desired output, using the word **sopa**, should be like the following:

```
sopa
sop4
sop@
s0pa
s0p4
s0p@
$opa
$op4
$op@
$0pa
$0p4
$0p@
§opa
§op4
§op@
§0pa
§0p4
§0p@
5opa
5op4
5op@
50pa
50p4
50p@
```

I appreciate any help. Thank y'all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track. Here is your modified function without recursion or itertools. This code also allows the function to take either a single word or a list of words.

```
def type4 (words):
    chars = {'A': ['4', '@'],'E': ['3', '€', '&', '£'],'T': ['7'],'S': ['$', '§', '5'],
         'I': ['1', '!'],'O': ['0'],'B': ['8'],'C': ['<'],'L': ['1']}
    tmp = []
    #This allows you to take a single word or list of words as argument
    if type(words) is str:
        tmp = [words]
    elif type(words) is list:
        tmp.extend(words)

    for word in tmp:
        for letter in word:
            if letter.upper() in chars:
                for new_letter in chars[letter.upper()]:
                    new_word = word.replace(letter, new_letter)
                    tmp.append(new_word)
    return set(tmp)

print(type4("sopa"))
#{'$op@', '$opa', 's0pa', '$0pa', '§opa', '5op@', '§0pa', '$0p4', '50pa', '$op4', 'sopa', '$0p@', 's0p4', '5op4', '§op@', '5opa', '50p4', '§0p@', '50p@', 'sop4', '§0p4', '§op4', 's0p@', 'sop@'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have an easier time doing this with [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Here's how, explanation follows:

```py
chars = ... # paste your code from above

def type4(word):
    positions = []  # will hold the list of character options for each letter    
    for letter in word:
        positions.append([letter] + chars.get(letter.upper(), []))
    
    return [''.join(combo) for combo in itertools.product(*positions)]
```

The `for letter in words` loop looks up each letter (in uppercase) in the `chars` dictionary and adds the list of chars for that letter, along with the letter into `positions`.

- `chars.get(letter.upper(), [])` attempts to find the key (upper case letter) in `chars`. If it does, then returns it, otherwise, returns the default value provided, which is an empty list `[]` in this case.

  - So for 's' in 'sopa', it would be `['s'] + ['$', '§', '5']` = `['s', '$', '§', '5']`
  - And for 'p', since it's not there, it would be `['p'] + []` = `['p']`
  - See [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) for details.
  - Using `dict.get` replaces the need for `if letter in chars.keys()`
- For clarity, a longer version of the same loop:

  ```py
  positions = []
  for letter in word:
      if letter.upper() in chars.keys():
          options = chars[letter.upper()]
      else:
          options = []
      positions.append([letter] + options)
  ```
- Or in just one line:

  ```py
  positions = [[letter] + chars.get(letter.upper(), []) for letter in word]
  ```

After that loop, `positions` will be a list containing lists of characters, one list for each letter in the word provided:

```py
[
    ['s', '$', '§', '5'],
    ['o', '0'], 
    ['p'], 
    ['a', '4', '@']
]
```

2nd loop/return statement:

- `itertools.product` creates all the possible combinations from each list of options it has (see the docs), and provides that in a consistent sequence.
- The `*positions` basically expands it into individual lists (one for each char, so 4 in the example)
- Then `product` uses one item from each of those lists and provides them as a tuple, like `('§', '0', 'p', '4')`.
- [`''.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) turns the tuple (or list, or any iterable) into one string.
- If that single `return` line is confusing, consider this longer form:

  ```py
  tmp = []  # as per your code
  for combo in itertools.product(*positions):
      tmp.append(''.join(combo))
  return tmp
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem fits really nicely within a recursion paradigm. I have comments in the below code, but as a short explanation:

This is one function that will iterate through a dictionary and slowly accumulate new permutations of a given word. Once the value.lower() has been found inside your current word, it will create a new word to find all permutations of. This works by calling generate_permutations_of_word each time you find a match.

```
# instantiate replacement_dictionary
replacement_dictionary = {
    'A': ['4', '@'],
    'E': ['3', '€', '&', '£'],
    'T': ['7'],
    'S': ['$', '§', '5'],
    'I': ['1', '!'],
    'O': ['0'],
    'B': ['8'],
    'C': ['<'],
    'L': ['1']
}

def generate_permutations_of_word(word, all_permutations=None):
    # if not yet instantiated, start with first word
    all_permutations = all_permutations or {word}
    
    # iterate over the replacement dictionary
    for replace_this, replace_with_value_list in replacement_dictionary.items():
        
        # iterate over the values in the "value" of the value_list
        for replace_with in replace_with_value_list:
            
            # if it matches
            if replace_this.lower() in word.lower():
                
                # new sub_word
                new_sub_word = word.replace(replace_this.lower(), replace_with.lower())
                
                # add this sub word to our list
                all_permutations.add(new_sub_word)
                
                # also find permutations of this subword
                all_permutations = generate_permutations_of_word(new_sub_word, all_permutations)
                
    return all_permutations

for x in generate_permutations_of_word('sopa'):
    print(x)
```